# Angular Web Page with too many charts is sluggish when scrolled

Tags: javascript, angular, charts

I'm currently working on Angular 6. I'm fetching data dynamically from my backend and creating views dynamically.

My views include Various Graphs like BarChart, LineChart, GeoChart..etc

I have created separate components for each chart and I'm reusing them to bind the views dynamically. Everything is working fine when there are few charts involved (around 6-10). But, when I load a view which has too many charts (>15), the webpage is getting stuck sometimes and the scroll is very sluggish.

What is causing this behavior? How can I solve it? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should wite down your code. maybe the one for that specific component so that we'll really get what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Performance is a very broad subject. As already mentioned you should provide more implementation details to get the right advice/help. Maybe you can create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) which demonstrates the issue. For what its worth, you can checkout the following:

```
* ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush - one-way data binding
* IntersectionObserver - Only build the graph when it is visible
```